# How can I create a facebook-style timeline, but with responsive design in 3 different styles?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

#### How can I create a facebook-style timeline, but with responsive design in 3 different styles?

#### What it is expected to be

#### Code:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="item item-1">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-6">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-1">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
        blablabla....
    </div>
    <!-- It just goes on and on... -->
</div>
```

#### Desktop (min-width:980px)

3 boxes in a row that line according to their numbers.
`.item-1` and `.item-4` go to the first row, `.item-2` and `.item-5` go to the second row, and so on.

#### Tablet (min-width:768px)

2 boxes in a row. `.item-1` `.item-3` and `.item-5` go to the first row, `.item-2` `.item-4` and `.item-6` go to the second row.

#### Phone (max-width:767px)

Simply line them on a single row.

### Additional Info

This style should fit to any height of content.
Like this:
[image: diagram]
OR something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/) is also accepted that does not require the boxes into the correct column, as long as they are placed evenly and looks in the correct order.

*Sorry for my poor English, I'm a Chinese. But fell free to write anything. I can read them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Masonry with different width of box in different displays will do.

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Numbering of items is not required.